# Remove Space below AndroidPlot

Tags: java, android, androidplot

I have found the following post during looking for a solution to remove space below my AndroidPlot.

[How do I remove all space around a chart in AndroidPlot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14059553/how-do-i-remove-all-space-around-a-chart-in-androidplot/48523710#48523710)

```
Widget gw = mPlot.getGraph();    
    Size size = new Size(0,SizeMode.FILL,0,SizeMode.FILL);    
    gw.setSize(size);
    gw.position(0, HorizontalPositioning.ABSOLUTE_FROM_LEFT,0, VerticalPositioning.ABSOLUTE_FROM_TOP);
```

I am not sure, if this Solution still works or if the solution doesn't work anymore or if I simply made an error while implementing it.

A picture to make it more clear:

[image]

Thanks for help,

Franzi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was more simple than I thought.

I solved the problem by add thing the following code:

```
mPlot.getGraph().setMarginBottom(0);
```